как заменить картинки на сайте
Для курсовой работы делаю маленький интернет магазин, делаю по видео урокам, у меня не получается загрузить свои картинки (фон, товары).
на снимке 1 я показал папку, где хранятся рисунки, вначале я заменил картинку с фоном, но ничего не поменялось, тогда я удалил картинку, но фон как был так и остался, подскажите, как мне заменить их, почему при удалении/замены ничего на сайте не происходит?
среда разработки - VS Cod / Django


Покажите код, которым вы эти картинки устанавливаете. Код должен быть текстом.






Как кортинки и css связаны между собой? Какой итоговый путь получается на клиенте? Нет ли там ошибок в консоли и вкладке сеть(network)?

в css идет ссылка на фоновую картинку: background-image: url("../images/bg-image1.jpg"), но я картинку полностью удалил из проекта, почему при запуске сервера она отображается? по идее фон должен пропасть?

Смотрите вкладку сеть. Может закэшировалось чего, а может из другого места тащит

я так понимаю, это вкладка network?! но у меня ее нет... я еще не в теме, а где она находится?

F12 в браузере нажимаете и появится "Developer tool"/"Инструменты разработчика"

Может попробовать CTRL+F5, перезагрузить страницу с принудительной загрузкой новой, некешированной версии
